# Cosine similarity between lists is not being calculated

Tags: python, apply, cosine-similarity

I'm currently trying to calculate the similarity between lists and create a new column on my dataframe showing the result. However, when I try to do this, it returns 0 for all entries of my data (like is shown below)

```
        list1                   list2                   similarity
[action, adventure,...]   [[zoe_saldana, action,...],..]    [0.0, 0.0,...]
         ...                     ...                       ...
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
def counter_cosine_similarity(c1, c2):
    terms = set(c1).union(c2)
    dotprod = sum(c1.get(k, 0) * c2.get(k, 0) for k in terms)
    magA = math.sqrt(sum(c1.get(k, 0)**2 for k in terms))
    magB = math.sqrt(sum(c2.get(k, 0)**2 for k in terms))
    try:
        return dotprod / (magA * magB)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass


#SIMILARITY#
def get_similarity (row):
        similarities = []
        for idx, list_of_lists in enumerate(row['list1']):
                for l1 in list_of_lists:
                        counter_list1=Counter(l1)
                        counter_list2 = Counter(row['list2'])
                        similarities.append(counter_cosine_similarity(counter_list1,counter_list2))

        return similarities

frame['similarity']=frame.apply(lambda row: get_similarity(row), axis=1)
```

I have been trying to understand what it's happening, but I haven't reached a conclusion. Especially because when I do it the way done below, the similarity list returns correct values:

```
similarity=[]
for idx, list_of_lists in enumerate(frame['list1']):
        for l1 in list_of_lists:
                counter1=Counter(l1)
                for idx1 , l2 in enumerate(frame['list2']):
                        counter2=Counter(l2)
                        if idx==idx1:
                        similarity.append(counter_cosine_similarity(counter1,counter2))
```

If anyone has can help, I'd very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're able to get the similarities correct when you just appended them to a list, is there a reason you can't do:

```
frame['similarity'] = similarity
```

Comment: the only reason that is not working is because the lengths of the list and the dataframe are different (there are rows for which list2 has 2 or more lists inside the list of lists). But that could be solved. I just really wanted to understand what I'm doing wrong with the first implementation, as it seems pretty similar to the second

Comment: @J.Doe it's probably a different length because you need to fix that indent under 'if idx==idx1:'. similarity.append(counter_cosine_similarity(counter1,counter2)) should be tabbed over so it happens only under the if condition, right now it's not

Comment: @J.Doe if you post the full code with how you're importing and creating that list as well as the values of the lists, I can run it on my computer and figure it out. With what you provided, I can't run your actual code